# sIFR 3 not working in IE6 or IE7

Tags: sifr, sifr3

Works great everywhere but IE 6 and IE 7, any help?

http://www.zookacreative.com/beta

Comment: Looks nice.  The solution is to upgrade your browser.  Sorry to be a jerk, but the world needs to get used to things not working in IE6 (and even IE7)

Comment: Not supporting IE 6 I can see, but IE7 is a bit over the top if you are targeting a mainstream audience. Anyway, in this case, if I am right, IE was right in its intepreation and FF was wrong.

Comment: Pekka was right, it now works in both IE6 and IE7!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the error is in your [sifr-config.js](http://www.zookacreative.com/beta/js/sifr-config.js):

```
 sIFR.replace(nfslab, {
    selector: '#home h3.about,#ourapproach h3.about,#contactus h3.about, #mobile h3.about, #web h3.about, #affiliate h3.about, #environments h3.about, #branding h3.about, #packaging h3.about, #pop h3.about, #print h3.about',
  wmode: 'transparent',
  css: [
        '.sIFR-root { background-color: #FFFFFF; color: #000000; font-size: 16px; text-decoration: none; cursor: pointer; }',
        'a {color: #000000; text-decoration: none;}',
        'a:hover {color: #6BC8C6; text-decoration: none;}'
        ],
});
```

the trailing comma in the list is graciously ignored by Firefox, but not by IE. 
This screws up the siFR initialization process.
I think IE is correct to fail here.
You will need to remove all extra commas in all definitions.

Comment: Which comma are you talking about? I tried to remove some with no good results. Any help?

Comment: woohoo! Thank you very much Pekka! You were right, and it nows works properly in both IE6 and IE7. Good day sir!